# Must declare the scalar value @Tx1

Tags: mysql

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim Tx1 As String

        Tx1 = TextBox1.Text

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBTestX.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Test) VALUES(@Tx1)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()


    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see and visualize in this code, there is only 1 form, 1 textbox and 1 button.

Using VB Express 2010 and SQL Server 2008, I created an SQL database and table via clicking `Project > Add New Item > Service-Based Database`, etc. All I want to do is to insert the new data which I have on the textbox1 into the only column on the table. However, I'm not able to do so.

Can you please help me to point out the cause of the problem? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to add the `@Tx1` parameter and set its value:

```
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Test) VALUES(@Tx1)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tx1", SqlDbType.VarChar, <length of your column>).Value = Tx1
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You'll need to supply the length when adding the parameter.

Also, I don't use VB.NET that often so I may have slipped into C# with my example; apologies in advance if that's the case :)

Comment: Thank you so much... I think it works.. however when i open the DBTestX.mdf the name of database file.. by right click then Show data table... the data is not there.. there is no data inserted... do i have to add a new code? or im viewing it wrongly? thank you so much

Comment: how do i mark this as answered? Thank you so much for the info ^_^

Comment: I'm terrible with VB.NET but I'll try to help. The only thing I can think of is: was there an uncaught exception? Could you try stepping through the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` in the debugger to see if it proceeds normally to `cmd.Close`? If it doesn't you should be able to view the Exception it throws. And if you can't view the exception try surrounding the `cmd.Parameters.Add` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` in a `try`/`catch`. Let me know what you see...

Comment: I will try it now.. thank you so much for your help and patience ^_^

Comment: i tried to debug but no issue...I put "Try" at the bottom of "Dim Tx1 As String"...i put " Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")   still no issue... =(
        Finally" after "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" then "con.Close()
            MsgBox("Database Closed")" then end try..

Comment: Hmm. Normally I'd think the insert wasn't committed but I think most drivers auto-commit. Which driver are you using? Also, can you try refreshing the grid that shows `TestTable` results? You can do that by right-clicking over it and selecting `Refresh`.

Comment: As for how to accept the answer... first: thanks! second: I have no clue how to do that :) I think if you hover around the "vote" area (where the uparrow/downarrow are) you'll light up a checkmark that you can click on. If I had to guess I'd say it was to the left because that's where it displays once the answer has been accepted.

Comment: how do i give thanks here? someone also posted that using the attachfile is not really a good way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305152/insert-data-on-sql-table-cannot-find-the-data

Comment: however i stilll do not understand what they meant...=(

Comment: Good idea to put this problem out there separately. I never would have figured out that "attach file" thingie. You can hover to the left of their comment and a "helpful" button will appear. That'll flag the comment as helpful, which is a form of thanks. As for creating the database, right-click "Database" in the tree and you'll see a "New Database" option. Click that, enter a name (without spaces), leave all the settings as their default, and click "Add". Use the name you entered as the "new database" in your connect string.

Comment: Thank you very very very much... now im a step closer in gaining my goal... thank you so much and god bless you ^_^