# Insert data on SQL Table... cannot find the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

VB express 2010

1 form, 1 textbox , 1 button

I created the .mdf sql database file by clicking `Project>add new item>service based database>` and named it DXDB - table name DXtest and 1 column named test

It seems like the codes works..however when I right click DXtest and click show table data... there is nothing there... =( It seems like it doesnt really insert the data on the database itself...

Here is the complete code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim Tx1 As String

        Tx1 = TextBox1.Text

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DXDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DXTest(Test) VALUES(@Tx1)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tx1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Tx1
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Stop, stop, stop using AttachDbFileName/User Instance features. What's happening is you are connecting to two different copies of your database. Attach your database to an instance of SQL Server and use a connection string directly to that instance.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: couldn't agree more! Maybe you need to put this into a *Bad Habits To Kick* blog post :-)

Comment: if you dont mind.. may you please provide a step by step on how to? thank you so much for your replies

Answer (score 5):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `DXDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DXDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: I really do not understand this... im very very good at access but not sql.. can anyone tell me how to connect the database i created on SSMS? i tried to connect it by new data source and change the data source to Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DXDB;Integrated Security=True however this gives me an instance error... please if you may, provide a step by step starting from creating the database on SSMS (by the way im using Microsoft SQL server Management...theres no express... and also the step by step on how to connect it to my project,..Thank you so much

Comment: @MarkDarwinCortezBuentipo: well, if you **created** the database on SQL Server - then **how** (using **what** server name?) did you connect to it to be able to create the database?? Use that server name in your connection! Also: if you have an error - ***please*** tell us ***exactly*** what it is - don't just tease about it - we need to ***complete and exact*** error message

Comment: it shows an "Instance Failure" even with try and catch excemptions.. thank you so much for everyones reply.. im really a new on this and thank you for your patience